# Is there a way when using boost.python on windows to only load pythonXX.dll on demand?

Tags: windows, dll, wrapper, ctypes, boost-python

I have a C API DLL we created for a USB product we make that I thought would be nice to be able to import with python without using any wrapping functions like ctypes. Our DLL is already statically linked with boost and the C runtime for other functionality without any problems. Once I add any exported python functions such as this simple test:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

The DLL that gets built now depends on python34.dll at load time. Normally this would be fine, but the reality is that most users of our DLL currently aren't going to use the python functionality. What I would like to happen is to only have this dependency if the module gets loaded by python, or when a python function gets called for the first time. That way only python users would need to have the python DLL, and our DLL would not get an error loading on systems that lack the python DLL when not being loaded by python code.

On solution I can think of would be to create a separate DLL just for python users that either calls our DLL or includes all of its functionality. I would prefer to just have one binary if possible though. Once there are two or more files involved I question the value over just distributing a wrapper written in python using ctypes.

In my own Windows C/C++ code, I always load whatever DLLs I can on-demand so that I can do better error reporting to the user and maybe allow the program to run with crippled functionality if it is not there. I was a little surprised that boost.python was pulling in python34.dll right at load time.

Comment: Look into linking Python as a [delay-loaded DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx).

Comment: I am not the one loading the python DLL - boost.python is. I know how to delay-load a DLL, but I'm wondering if I can get boost.python to do this without rewriting it. As it stands linking to boost.python creates a pythonXX.dll dependency at load time even if the DLL is being loaded by a non-python application.

Comment: What you're asking for probably isn't possible. Boost.Python is intended to extend and embed Python, so it may require Python's C API at startup. In that case building a separate Python extension that links to your DLL is the way to go.

Comment: Plus, IMO, it's preferable to use a .pyd file extension for an extension module. Python's import system doesn't look for .dll files (unlike .so files on Linux), so you have to manually load the .dll using `imp.load_dynamic` (or using importlib -- get a loader and a spec, then create and exec a module).